Firebase Notification is showing but on click notification not opening the app
I am using Firebase Notification
on my app I am getting notification properly but when I click on the notification my app is not opening
this is my class
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    Intent intent ;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        String body = "";
        String title = "";
        String type = "";
        String json_Data = "";
        String referenceId = "";

        Log.d("FirebaseMsgService", "Message received: " + remoteMessage);

        try {

            if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {

                body = Objects.requireNonNull(remoteMessage.getNotification()).getBody();
                title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
                type = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();
               /* body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
                title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();*/

                Log.d("FirebaseMsgService", "Notification received - Title: " + title + ", Body: " + body + ", Type: " + type);

            }

            referenceId =   remoteMessage.getData().get("refrence_id");
         //   type = remoteMessage.getData().get("click_action"); // Get the click_action

            Log.d("FirebaseMsgService", "Reference ID: " + referenceId);


        }catch (Exception e){
            type ="";
            Log.d("FirebaseMsgService", "" + e.toString());
            Log.d("FirebaseMsgService",e.toString() + "" +e.getMessage().toString());
        }

        sendNotification(body , title , type , referenceId);

    }

    private void sendNotification(String body , String title , String noti_type , String postId) {

        Log.d("FirebaseMsgService", "Intent Data: noti_type=" + noti_type + ", postId=" + postId);


        if(noti_type.equals("disscussion_board")){
            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailDiscussionActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("borad_id" , postId);
            intent.putExtra( "sss" ,bundle);
        } else if(noti_type.equals("sell_vehicle")){
            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CarListForSaleActivty.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("sell_id" , postId);
            bundle.putString("title" , title);
            intent.putExtra( "sss" ,bundle);
        } else if (noti_type.equals("portable_charger_booking")) {
            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PortableChargerBookingHistoryDetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("booking_id" , postId);
            intent.putExtra("title" , title);
           // intent.putExtra( "sss" ,bundle);

        } else if (noti_type.equals("charging_service")) {
            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChargingServiceHistoryDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("service_id" , postId);
            intent.putExtra("title" , title);
            // intent.putExtra( "sss" ,bundle);

        }else if(noti_type.equals("charging_installation_service")){
            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChargerInstallationHistoryDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("requestId" , postId);
            intent.putExtra("title" , title);
        }else {
            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationListActivity.class);
        }
        int requestCode = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channelId");

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("channelId", getString(R.string.app_name), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            channel.setShowBadge(true);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            notificationBuilder.setChannelId("channelId");
        }

        Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(body))
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000})
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


        Random rand = new Random();
        int as = rand.nextInt();
//        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(as /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}

and nothing is printing on Logs
this is data coming from server
"message": {
    "token": "dSfgsgsfdgsdfgdsfxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "notification": {
      "title": "Completed!",
      "body": "complete body ."
    },
    "data": {
      "title": "Charging Completed!",
      "body": "Charging complete, please lock your EV.",
      "click_action": "portable_charger_booking",
      "refrence_id": "PCB0305"
    },
    "apns": {
      "payload": {
        "aps": {
          "sound": "default"
        }
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "priority": "high",
      "notification": {
        "click_action": "portable_charger_booking"
      }
    }
  }
}

everything i have added like in manifest intent-filter but the main problem is i am not getting any logs when notification is coming
I am expecting on click on notification my app will open
